# No major tick marks showing using seaborn white style and cannot restore

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

When I generate plots using the seaborn "white" style I see major tick **labels** but I don't see any major tick **marks**.

Setting major tick marks to be bigger using...

```
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('white', {'axes.linewidth': 0.5})
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 20
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 4

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.show()
```

...has no effect.

I can't find any option that would make the tick **marks** visible/invisible.

Anybody have any clues?

Comment: It would appear that one of my own packages (lost in the mists of time) executes import seaborn as sns and sns.set_style('white', {'axes.linewidth': 0.5}).  This kills the major tickmarks in some serious, difficult to recover from way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rcParams `'xtick.major.size'` and `'xtick.major.width'` can indeed be used to change the length and width of the ticks. The rcParams `'xtick.bottom'` and `'ytick.left'` can be used to set the ticks on or off.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('white', {'axes.linewidth': 0.5})
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 20
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 4
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = True
plt.rcParams['ytick.left'] = True

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem in the question is that the tick marks are not visible. So changing their size has no effect...

Comment: I suppose if the question wanted to ask about why the ticks are not visible, it would have provided a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : You are correct and if I'd done that I'd have realized the cause (using a seaborn style) earlier. Though not the solution which still evades me.  The seaborn style is not setting the major ticks to zero length or width but literally making them invisible in some manner.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : I've added an illustrative example.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Ahhh!.  I'd seen them when I waded through rcParams keys but not twigged what they did.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

### Use the `'ticks'` style

This is a [built-in style](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html#seaborn-figure-styles) for the exact purpose of having `'white'` style with tick marks:

```
sns.set_style('ticks')  # white style with tick marks
```

[image]

---

If you really want to use the `'white'` style or just want to modify tick params, it's simplest to pass an `rc` dict:

```
sns.set_style('white', rc={
    'xtick.bottom': True,
    'ytick.left': True,
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In case one wants to *not* mess with global rcParams, but manually tune by plot, one can use [`ax.tick_params()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('white', {'axes.linewidth': 0.5})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(bottom=True, left=True)
plt.show()
```

The critical part is "enabling" the tick marks - in this case the bottom and left marks were enabled. If one wants marks on the four sides, using `ax.tick_params(reset=True)` might also be an option, though I'm not sure how this might affect other Seaborn tunings.

There are also a number of options listed [in the function documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) that might be useful, although they do not apply directly to OP.

**Note:** this answer also works for other styles, including the default one, not just `'white'`.